# Word for space-origination

Tags: pronunciation

How could you say something is from space? For instance, californian, french, american, etc. Spactian sounds like something that could perhaps be correct, but the spelling's transposition into pronunciation sounds different than the actual pronunciation, which should be spay-shean. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Spatial:1. of or pertaining to space.2. existing or occurring in space.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spatial

Comment: @Josh61 That doesn't quite seem right, seeing as thefreedictionary.com's definition of american is "a native or inhabitant of America".

Comment: Do you mean from outer-space? If so, have you considered extraterrestrial?

Comment: Does *of or pertaining to space* not cover your needs?

Comment: @Avon I have, but the definition of that is more anything that is not from Earth, and I'd rather specifically from space, excluding planets and such.

Comment: @Josh61 No, because I'm talking about something specifically originating to space, not something with space-related aspects.

Comment: What about *cosmic*? Of or relating to the universe or cosmos, especially as distinct from the earth:

Comment: I see, so something coming from interplanetary, interstellar or intergalactic space. I don't think there is a less specific word than those three. Edit: Except possibly cosmic

Comment: Ok, thanks! I think I'm going to have to go with cosmic though, as that suits my needs most. Thank you!

Comment: "Extraterrestrial" means precisely "not from Earth".  "Cosmic" is somewhat vaguer and can mean extraterrestrial, something more distant (outside the Solar System, eg), or something abstract and ethereal (eg, imaginary or fictitious).

Comment: I was going to say **Aetherian**, not that I'd heard it, but it makes sense.) However, I see that it has been coined to refer to a fantasy world, a doppleganger Earth, with its own language. http://ehkindred.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/The-Aetherian-Dictionary.pdf   . . If Aetherian means otherworldly, I wonder if the Aetherians would call _us_ Aetherian?   Oh, and there's also an "rtherean" church http://conscioushumanity.org/blog/etherean-mission/

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Same thing as aliens calling us alien... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cosmic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cosmic) may fit your needs:

> - Of or relating to the universe or cosmos, especially as distinct from the earth: *cosmic matters*
>     (ODO)

Answer (score 3):

"Cosmic" -- from the cosmos.

"Extraterrestrial" -- from anywhere other than Earth.

"Space" is the space between places, so it doesn't lend itself readily to being used as an origin. Anything in Space must have come from somewhere else ...

Comment: Thank you, to clarify I did mean Space as more of a proper noun, pertaining specifically to the space between extra-terrestrial objects as a place in and of itself.